# mobilyzer.py WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, security, testing, dynamic

I'm trying to run a ready python script (called m0biliz3r) which I downloaded from this [link](https://github.com/SudhanshuC/Android-Testing/blob/8b872e637be97cb3ae5c1aa8a5458bcace6bdcb2/moblizer). It is basically for performing dynamic security testing of android .apk files.

So while executing the python script I get the following error screen on my Windows7 (64 bit).

```css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moblizer.py", line 47, in <module>
    call(["apktool","d",b])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The contents of the current file folder from where I'm executing the moblizer.py script are as follows.

```css
C:\Python27>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is A6D5-3E2A

 Directory of C:\Python27

25-May-16  07:16 PM    <DIR>          .
25-May-16  07:16 PM    <DIR>          ..
25-May-16  07:15 PM    <DIR>          apktool
14-Feb-16  08:09 PM    <DIR>          DLLs
14-Feb-16  08:09 PM    <DIR>          Doc
22-May-16  04:11 PM        25,996,792 FTP_v8.3_1905.apk
19-May-16  02:12 PM        25,954,247 FT_v10.0_0605.apk
14-Feb-16  08:09 PM    <DIR>          include
07-Mar-16  03:27 PM    <DIR>          Lib
14-Feb-16  08:09 PM    <DIR>          libs
05-Dec-15  08:45 PM            38,584 LICENSE.txt
25-May-16  07:33 PM               422 logfile.log
25-May-16  07:34 PM             4,206 moblizer.py
05-Dec-15  08:25 PM           444,900 NEWS.txt
05-Dec-15  08:41 PM            28,160 python.exe
05-Dec-15  08:41 PM            28,160 pythonw.exe
21-Nov-15  11:03 PM            56,557 README.txt
14-Feb-16  09:16 PM    <DIR>          Scripts
13-Mar-16  09:46 AM    <DIR>          sqlmap
14-Feb-16  08:09 PM    <DIR>          tcl
14-Feb-16  08:09 PM    <DIR>          Tools
               9 File(s)     52,552,028 bytes
              12 Dir(s)  25,998,880,768 bytes free
```

I appreciate any help and advice how to resolve am not a programmer or developer.

Comment: Seems that script requires [apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply dizballanze. But actually I do have apktool folder in C:\Python27\apktool location. Or do I need to check something else ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a solution then, open moblizer file in any text editor, i.e notepad++ , then go to line 47, in there change 'apktool' to 'apktool.bat' and save the file. Your problem should be solved.